# bash: group-by or merge lines choosing max timestamp

Tags: bash, sorting, merge, group-by, max

I have an input like this:

```
A 05 something
B 03 something1
A 02 something43
A 01 somethingelse
C 03 something2
B 10 something
C 01 somethingagain
```

and I would like to output:

```
A 05 something
B 10 something
C 03 something2
```

That is I group by the first field and choose the greatest number. The number is a fixed-length timestamp in my case, so you can use alphabetical sorting to get the greatest one. I'd prefer to do it with some command line tools and I guess it can be done in some easy way but haven't succeeded until now. Please no regex hell, the more readable, the better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sort twice:

```
< input sort -rk2,2 | sort -k1,1 -u
```

The first sort sorts by the 2nd column (`-r` for reversed), the second sorts by the first columns and uniques (`-u`).

Comment: I somehow get the ideea, but it does not output what OP desires.

Comment: @FlorinGhita: It works for me. Maybe you need to set `LC_ALL=C` to cancel locale settings?

Comment: hmm, didn't manage to make it work. Tried with LC_ALL=C and LC_ALL=en_US but it return A 01
B 03
C 03

Comment: @FlorinGhita: Sounds like missing `-r`.

Comment: first sort returns: B 10
A 05
C 03
B 03
A 02
A 01

Comment: @FlorinGhita: What OS, what `sort`? What does `man sort` say about `-u`?

Comment: SunOS 5.10  /  I don't know how to find the version of `sort`. I tried with `sort --version` but don't recognize it and prints the usage. The man page is last edited on 19 nov 2001 :))

Comment: _-u Unique: suppresses all but one in  each  set of lines having equal keys. If used with the -c option, checks that there  are  no  lines with  duplicate keys in addition to checking that the input file is sorted._ My unix doesn't seem to be too modern :)

Comment: @FlorinGhita: Yes, mine says  *output only the first of an equal run*

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk an store the results in an array:

```
cat input | awk '{if (a[$1] < $2) a[$1]=$2;} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i];}'
```

$1 if first column $2 is the second column.
This part: `{if (a[$1] < $2) a[$1]=$2;}` just update the array with current value if the value is greater than the value already stored in the array (by default is zero).

This part `END {for (i in a) print i, a[i];}'` runs after the input is exhausted and just print the vector.

UPDATE: To answer to the update of the OP: use another vector to store the entire line:

```
cat input | awk '{if (a[$1] < $2) {a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$0;}} END {for (i in a) print b[i];}'
```

Comment: If you have large inputs, this will be fastest, because it does no sorts. But I'm not sure how it manages memory if the input is huuuge(many GBs).

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the second field in reverse ascending order and the first in ascending order and print only the first value for the key column using awk:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2r,2 input.txt | awk '{ if (! F[$1]) print; F[$1]=1  }'
```

The awk script prints the whole line if it hasn't seen the key in the first column already. Then it remembers the key in the first column so it won't be printed if seen again.